# how to properly address the link tags for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I developed a website using HTML and CSS which is working fine on desktop but when I copied my site folder into mobile it didn't load my CSS and JS files.so what should I do?

```
    <head>
    <title>mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <script src="./scripted.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: If you are using a separate folder to run on mobile, you must define the source path as `./path/mobile/source`. In this case: `./mobile/style.css` and `./mobile/scripted.js`

Comment: There is normally no difference between mobile and desktop sites when it comes to reading external files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Chrome DevTools "Remote Debugging Android Devices" as described here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

In my opinion, this is the most convenient way to test your HTML page.

Another way to open an HTML file on your mobile, with all the scripts and styles, is to deploy a local server that will be accessible within your local network and configure it to return an HTML page with all its dependencies.

As far as I know, just opening an HTML file with styles and scripts that are rendered into other files will not work.

By the way, you can place your CSS and JS code in a file with HTML, but it seems to me that this is not a very good solution.